# Keyboard shortcut to pull Google Chrome tab into its own window

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-extensions

Is there a keyboard short cut, or extension, that lets you rip a tab into a new window in Google Chrome instead of using the mouse?

Comment: IMHO: this really should be crtl+shift+u ('undock'), same as in Matlab... all of the solutions are annoying or at minimum dissatisfying

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A workaround would be: **Ctrl** + **L**, + **C**, + **W**, + **N**, + **V**, and **Enter**.

Or

**F6**, **Ctrl** + **C**, **Ctrl** + **N**, **Ctrl** + **V**, **Enter** and an optional **Alt** + **Tab**, **Ctrl** + **W**, **Alt** + **Tab**, to close the old tab.

You could automate the whole thing with [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/) (under Windows) and create a Hotkey for it (here, it's **Ctrl** + **Alt** + **x**):

```
HotKeySet("^!x", "split_tab")
Func split_tab()
    Send("{F6}^c^n")
    Sleep(999)
    Send("^v{Enter}")
    Send("!{Tab}^w!{Tab}")
EndFunc
```

I always have an additional application like this running in the background, offering useful keyboard shortcuts which automate and simplify tasks.

Alternatively, you can hit Ctrl + L instead of F6, which would be substantially easier as your hand does not have to leave the home row.

Comment: wish this was built in!  the disadvantage of this group of commands is it doesn't save your scroll position.

Comment: Well, that might be possible to preserve with some more code... I ain't got Chrome installed here, so I can't test this any more. But It shouldn't be much of a problem to read and set the vertical scroll bar position.

Comment: Or use Alt + D instead of Ctrl + L as their proximity is higher.

Comment: Ha, at first I thought this was some fancy incantation, then while following noticed that it's just **'jump to loc bar, copy URL, close tab, open new window, paste URL, and nav'**". Clever in its simplicity/straightforwardness/[Ruby slippers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_slippers#The_Wizard_of_Oz_(1939))-ness. ;^)

Comment: -- Here is a Mac/hammerspoon version of the above AutoIt shortcut
-- Only downside is it wipes the back history.
-- https://superuser.com/questions/182720/keyboard-shortcut-to-pull-google-chrome-tab-into-its-own-window
hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd", "ctrl"}, 'x', function() hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"cmd"}, "l")
   hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"cmd"}, "c")
   hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"cmd"}, "n")
   hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"cmd"}, "v")
   hs.eventtap.keyStroke({},"return")
   hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"cmd"}, "`")
   hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"cmd"}, "w")
   end)

Answer (score 95):

With the [Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb?hl=en) extension for Chrome, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> will move the current tab to a new window.

This was added in version 1.43 (2013-05-18), [Vimium on GitHub](https://github.com/philc/vimium).

Comment: Must have been added in a version newer than 27 as it is not present in that version.

Comment: Not sure if this is actually part of Chrome itself, but it works for me with [Vimium](http://vimium.github.io/) installed.

Comment: This shortcut isn't indeed part of Google Chrome but was introduced in Vimium v1.43 (2013-05-18).

Comment: Since VIM is an extension in Chrome, this will work on all platforms. By default, you can start with the modifier keys ctrl + x or alt + x, then pressing shift + w to invoke this functionality.

Comment: Is there any way to do the opposite? I mean, move the tabs from a window to another existing window

Comment: `Fdj` (upvote) thanks

Comment: @GabrielZiegler - shift W seems to do that for me.

Comment: Yo as if I needed another argument to get everyone from work on vim shortcuts.  Literally everyone uses Chrome.  So hype!!

Answer (score 37):

On Mac you can add custom shortcuts for any menu option. The option to detach a tab is named "Move Tab to New Window" (it has to be written **exactly** as in the menu, **including capitalization of letters**), so just add this to the shortcuts under settings (and select Application Google Chrome):
[image]

And then choose a shortcut, like <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or whatever (just make sure it's a unique combination, or it won't work).

Comment: This is excellent. Update for Big Sur, which still works for me: Select 'Shortcuts' menu at top of Keyboard Settings. Select 'App Shortcuts' from left hand menu. Press the '+' button to add an app shortcut.

Comment: Works from [Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.application.html) too: something like `app = hs.application.frontmostApplication()` or whatever to select the application, and then `app:selectMenuItem("Move Tab to New Window")` to simulate clicking on that item (and thus move the tab to a new window).

Comment: The menu title is case sensitive. So you must use the exact casing which as of v117 is `Move Tab to New Window`

Answer (score 23):

Just press `Cmd/Ctrl + L` and then `Shift + Enter`. However this refreshes the site and does not close the old tab. *Vimiums* `Shift + W` won't refresh the page and closes the old tab.

Comment: This is better than the selected answer since it's just two commands

Comment: also of note alt+d and then shift+enter works

Answer (score 18):

No *out-of-the-box* solution, but here is an [open-source](https://github.com/acarabott/tabToWindow) chrome extension that does exactly that, [Tab to Window/Popup](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-to-windowpopup-keyboa/adbkphmimfcaeonicpmamfddbbnphikh).

Answer (score 4):

In more recent versions of Chrome, you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to select the tab.

**This means you can now use the sequence <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>**

You can assign this sequence to a single hotkey combination by using tools such as AutoIt, AutoHotkey, or Phrase Express.

The advantage of using this method is that it doesn't reload the tab.

Comment: If you have the bookmarks bar visible, the first Shift+F6 puts you there -- press Shift+F6 again to select the first tab.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to add the Tab To Window Keyboard Shortcut extension. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-to-window-keyboard-sh/adbkphmimfcaeonicpmamfddbbnphikh?hl=en-GB

Personally I use Vimium and had just found the Shift+W and was loving it, since Ctrl+W closes a tab, having Shift+W open it in an new window made sense.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be a keyboard short cut built in.  Maybe auto-hot-keys can be used, but I'm not familiar with them.  I'm also assuming that you already know that dragging the tab out creates the tabs own window.

Comment: Ya, I know that dragging does that. I just wanted to see if there was a way to do it without the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

If you use voice recognition software [Dragon NaturallySpeaking](http://www.nuance.com/dragon/index.htm) (Windows/Mac, non-free), you can create the voice command:

```
Sub Main
    SendKeys "^l"
    Wait(0.2)
    SendKeys "^c"
    Wait(0.2)
    SendKeys "^w"
    Wait(0.2)
    SendKeys "^n"
    Wait(0.2)
    SendKeys "^v"
    Wait(0.2)
    SendKeys "{ENTER}"
End Sub
```

[image]

Annoyingly this reloads the page, which is not good in some situations, e.g. if the page contains a form you have started to fill.

Answer (score 0):

It's criminal that google doesn't provide a hotkey for this after all these years of people asking for it, but you can automate it with the following ahk script bound to winkey+n:

```
#n::
if (WinActive("ahk_exe chrome.exe"))
{
Send, {SHIFTDOWN}{F6}{F10}{SHIFTUP}m,{enter}{enter}
}
return
```

Note that shift-F6 only selects the current tab if there isn't a bookmark bar in your window. There's probably a workaround but I've not looked into it.