# Is there a keyboard shortcut for opening a tab in a new window on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, mac, keyboard, shortcuts, tabs

I'm aware this question was asked five years ago, but maybe there's been some changes since then. I'm also aware of the 'multiple keyboard shortcuts' that can be used.

In these days of sharing Zoom screens, I'm constantly finding myself right-clicking on tabs in order to open them in a new window. I find this a little fiddly - particularly if I'm using the trackpad.

Does a keyboard shortcut for this operation exist yet, or is CMD L, CMD C etc. still the only way to achieve this?

Comment: You edit people's posts here?

Comment: Would it be OK just to move the tab to a  new window, not keeping it in the current window? Because that can be done with simple drag & drop

Comment: Ah Laurent, this is excellent advice and is certainly the quickest way of doing it. Many thanks!

Comment: Those old enough to remember life before browser tabs are surprised to see this question

Comment: Why is that, Sridhar? (I should add that i remember life before browser tabs!)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard shortcut to pull Google Chrome tab into its own window](https://superuser.com/questions/182720/keyboard-shortcut-to-pull-google-chrome-tab-into-its-own-window)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to open a new tab in the same chrome window simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I asked; I'm looking to add the tab in a new window. Thank you for the reply though.

Comment: @fatar760 Ctrl + N if you want to open a new tab in a new google window. Is this what you want to ask?

Comment: I'm wishing to move an already opened tab to a new window. At the moment I need to right click on the tab in order to open it in a new window. Is there a keyboard shortcut for this action instead of right clicking? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The quickest way is to **drag the tab** label down and let the solo tab float. Is that a keyboard shortcut, no. But as your request just snowballed from "opening a tab in a new window on Chrome" into a different question, maybe we can take a slight liberty, too.

Comment: The question never changed, Yosef, but yes your advice matches Laurent's from earlier, which works a treat. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> opens existing Tab in a new window.
Tested on several Chromium based browsers at Windows 10

Comment: Shift + W did not work for me. I'm on a mac...

Comment: What is your exact Browser and version on Mac?

Comment: I'm on a macbook pro and I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: You can try to install Brave Browser (chromium based) and see it it still happen. https://brave.com/download/ . Is your chrome uptodate?

Comment: Yeh my Chrome is up to date. Is there a shortcut for normal Google Chrome?

Comment: This doesn't work for me neither on a up-to-date chrome on Windows 10...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't indeed want to keep the same page opened twice in existing window + new window, you can simply drag & drop the tab out of the current browser window, opening a new one with only this tab. I've tested this with Edge, Firefox and Chrome and the behavior seems to be consistent across these browsers.